# Rails 5: Attachinary auto submit after upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-5, cloudinary

I have an application on Heroku where I use [attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary) to upload photos to Cloudinary. I like to know if there is some way or fallback where I can automatically submit the form after the attachinary upload is finished. Someone can Help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the [attachinary's document](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary#usage), the gem has a jQuery plugin that based on the [jQuery Fileupload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), so that you can always add an event handler to jQuery Fileupload's events to control your business needs.

There is a list of events that jQuery Uploadfile provides at [wiki - Callback Options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options) so I think you can do like:

```
$("#your-upload-input").bind("fileuploaddone", function _doSubmit (event, data) {
  $("#your-form").submit();
})
```

Moreover, you can look into the way how *attachinary* collaborate with that plugin at [attachinary.js.coffee](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary/blob/98a895be22edc74b1928ffa3ae116d24bd9818fd/lib/assets/javascripts/attachinary.js.coffee#L89-L90), we can see that the gem use the similar way with the code snippet above.

Hope you can find a proper way to handle your needs